# mysql 5.1 innodb_file_per_table не активируется

Tags: mysql, linux, база-данных, ubuntu, innodb

Имеется сервер: Ubuntu 16.04.
Необходимо собрать Mysql 5.1.55 с `innodb_file_per_table`.

Конфигурирую с такими опциями:

```
./configure '--localstatedir=/db/mysql' '--with-system-type=debian-linux-gnu'
 '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--enable-thread-safe-client' 
'--enable-assembler' '--enable-local-infile' '--with-fast-mutexes'
 '--with-big-tables' '--with-unix-socket-path=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' 
'--with-mysqld-user=mysql' '--with-libwrap' '--with-readline' 
'--with-ssl' '--without-docs' '--with-extra-charsets=all' 
'--with-plugins=max' '--with-embedded-server' 
'--with-embedded-privilege-control'
```

> Файл my.cnf:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock


[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
skip-locking
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 128M
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 32M
event_scheduler = 1
max_connections = 300
thread_concurrency = 16
expire_logs_days = 3
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1
character-set-server = cp1251
collation-server = cp1251_ukrainian_ci
lower-case-table-names = 1

log-bin=mysql-bin

binlog_format=mixed

server-id       = 1


[innodb]
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /db/mysql
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 768M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
innodb_log_file_size = 100M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

При запуске сервера БД innodb_file_per_table = OFF
Остановил сервер БД, удалил все таблицы, выполнил: 
`mysql_install_db --user=mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Запустил сервер БД и все равно innodb_file_per_table = OFF????

Может есть какая то опция с конфигурацией --with-innodb-file-per-table ?
Как исправить ситуацию ?

Comment: Закомментируйте innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Веной всему был параметр innodb_log_file_size = 100M, когда его указывал - исчезали все параметры innodb (show variables), отключаешь - появляются.
2. Все параметры innodb - указал в категории [mysqld]